Reuse the same fragment in multiple navigation options of the same graph
I have a BottomNavigationView linked to a nav_graph.
I want that all my BottomNavigationView options open the same fragment. The option ID is used in the Java code to determine what to show in the fragment (this the same list of different items, the items depend of the selected option in the BottomNavigationView).
I succeed to show the fragment with the default option of the BottomNavigationView, but I can't select the other options. Is it possible to do that? And how?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

do not link them, instead use setOnItemSelectedListener on bottom navigation. With this you have more control.
